# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)) After Upgrading to Ruby on Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm upgrading my [open-source](https://github.com/havenweb/haven/blob/master/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb) Ruby on Rails app from Rails 6.0.x to Rails 6.1.x

The upgrade went fine, except now I get an error from an async ActiveJob that fetches RSS feeds.  When my app is deployed locally in development, I get one error:

```rb
[ActiveJob] [UpdateFeedJob] [80202040-f40d-46ae-8841-94cf03afbd6c] Error performing UpdateFeedJob (Job ID: 80202040-f40d-46ae-8841-94cf03afbd6c) from Async(default) in 366.36ms: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rss/rss.rb:53:in `w3cdtf'
/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:208:in `to_s'
...
/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:348:in `create'
/Users/matt/git/haven/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in update_feed'
/Users/matt/git/haven/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:79:in `each'
/Users/matt/git/haven/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:79:in `block in update_feed'
/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb:88:in `block in with_lock'
...
/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb:86:in `with_lock'
/Users/matt/git/haven/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:69:in `update_feed'
/Users/matt/git/haven/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:29:in `block in perform'
/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
...
```

When deployed remotely in production on AWS I get a slightly different error:

```rb
E, [2023-04-25T06:46:06.355616 #30503] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [UpdateFeedJob] [2996357f-8dd2-4b97-a367-e0be19fb5a16] Error performing UpdateFeedJob (Job ID: 2996357f-8dd2-4b97-a367-e0be19fb5a16) from Async(default) in 1526.52ms: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/time.rb:661:in `rfc2822'
/var/www/haven/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:208:in `to_s'
...
/var/www/haven/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:348:in `create'
/var/www/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in update_feed'
/var/www/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:79:in `each'
/var/www/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:79:in `block in update_feed'
/var/www/haven/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb:88:in `block in with_lock'
...
/var/www/haven/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb:86:in `with_lock'
/var/www/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:69:in `update_feed'
/var/www/haven/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb:29:in `block in perform'
/var/www/haven/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
...
```

On Rails 6.1, the [`active_support/time_with_zone.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L208) code calls:

```rb
utc.to_s(format)
```

Where on Rails 6.0 it [calls the same thing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L208).

Maybe the underlying `utc` object's type changed between Rails 6.0 and 6.1?  I'm trying to wrap my head around how to start debugging this.  It seems like a bug in Rails 6.1, but it could also be a bug I was relying on that got fixed in 6.1.  I tried upgrading from Ruby 2.7 to Ruby 3.0 and the issue persisted.

Any pointers on where to look next would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the code in your class, around the lines where the error is happening (`UpdateFeedJob`)?

Comment: It's a database put: `feed.feed_entries.create(record_data)` https://github.com/havenweb/haven/blob/113f3a8892be1e355b55ccb3e46f978b9e8c1799/app/jobs/update_feed_job.rb#L104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something to do with supported date formats.  I've got a resolution, but not a full understanding of what's going on.

The job is fetching RSS and Atom feeds using Ruby's built-in `rss` library which will generate a `Time` object from the feed xml (for feed entry publish time).  Depending on the feed or the format of the feed, it breaks--specifically xkcd.com's atom feed started breaking.

Saving a record with a `datetime` db type works fine if it is formatted as `Mon, 30 May 2022 00:00:00 +0000`, but breaks for something formatted as `2023-04-21T00:00:00Z`.  So I re-parse the time value: `time = Time.parse(time.httpdate)`.

I presume this is an interaction between what the rss library does with dates and what rails/activesupport does with dates.  Both rss-parsed strings self-report a type of `Time` but show original formats under `to_s`.  Activesupport also does some screwy things that made further debugging more challenging, [eg](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L41):

```rb
  class TimeWithZone
    # Report class name as 'Time' to thwart type checking.
    def self.name
      "Time"
    end
```

Comment: I guess you can follow part of your discoveries from [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L208) (reported in the error), which will assume `utc` is of a given type.

Comment: Both good and bad date objects self report their type as 'Time', and with a manual test, `.to_s(:db)` gives the same format output for each--hence my suspicion that one of them is actually a `TimeWithZone` or some other class.

Answer (score 1):

you need `.to_formatted_s` and pass in the symbol for your intended format

e.g.

```
Time.current.to_formatted_s(:mysql)
```